# Using a nested SQL query to select items in a specific subset and with a count>1

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to figure out how to select data from two tables where I select data with count>1 and only in a specific year. My current query is as follows:

```
SELECT table1.ID, table1.name, table1.data
FROM table1
WHERE  table1.ID IN (
    SELECT table2.ID
    FROM table2
    WHERE table2.year = '2020' AND table2.ID IN (
        SELECT table2.ID
        FROM table2
        GROUP BY table2.ID
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    )
);
```

However this retrieves data with count=1 in the given year if count>1 across multiple years. How do I write the query to exclude these?

Edit background: In table1 which I want output from I we have names and data related to the key ID this table does not change frequently, in table2 I am storing information updated yearly. I just want to select the id, name and data for those which occur in 2020 more than once, but not occurring more than once across multiple years.

Comment: Could you give us some table background as well give us some example on the data you have and the desired output please

Comment: Why are you quoting a number (`'2020'`)

Answer (score 0):

You could express this in as a join:

```sql
SELECT t1.ID, t1.name, t1.data
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ID
    FROM table2
    GROUP BY ID
    HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN year = 2020 THEN 1 END) > 0 AND COUNT(*) > 1
) t2
    ON t2.ID = t1.ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check both conditions in your `IN` clause:

```
Select table1.ID, table1.name, table1.data
From table1
WHERE  table1.ID IN (
    SELECT table2.ID
    FROM table2
    WHERE table2.ID IN (
        SELECT table2.ID
        FROM table2
        GROUP BY table2.ID
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 and
        table2.year = '2020')
);
```